# Installing Ubuntu 18.04 LTS in place of OpenSuse Leap 15.0 with a Windows/Linux dual-boot

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, multi-boot, opensuse

I gave it my best, but it seems my relationship with OpenSuse isn't working out and I'm going back to Ubuntu.

My current setup:

- Windows 10 Home (OEM installation from Lenovo) On factory HDD
- Opensuse Leap 15.0 On M.2 NVME SSD

Opensuse runs on the nvme ssd and windows on the factory hdd, and the two don't cross paths.

My concern is messing up the bootloaders.  When I installed opensuse, it handled everything like magic and left me with a nice dual boot setup.  Now I want to wipe the nvme ssd and install Ubuntu instead and have the exact same setup, but I'm concerned I might trash my windows boot.

My trouble is I don't get how the Ubuntu/Opensuse/InsertLinuxDistroHere detect existing OS's and create their boot menus.  If I format that NVME drive and install Ubuntu, will Ubuntu setup still detect the Windows install and create my dual-boot option?

Also any tips on what to select when going through Ubuntu install would be appreciated.

Comment: Trying to get through install now.  There's an erase and install option, but it wants to do it over my windows HDD and not my OpenSuse SSD.  Looks like I'll have to manually partition everything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was right to think the Ubuntu installer wouldn't give me the option to wipe out opensus.  Instead it gave me the option to wipe Windows (what do you have against Microsoft, Ubuntu?), or custom/advanced.

The advanced route gave me the option to wipe the nvme drive, but then I had to manually partition it.  Instead, I booted into Ubuntu, deleted the opensuse partions on my nvme drive, and then booted the installer back.  When I did that, the Ubuntu installer gave me the option to install alongside Windows, found the bootloader, and everything worked as expected.